# How to use displacement map in three.js for giving 3d effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d

I am trying to give 3d effect with displacement map in react, but my code is showing black screen. What is wrong with the code and how to implement it correctly?

```js
const 3dComponent= () => {
    const canvasRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvasRef.current });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const displacementMap = textureLoader.load(depth.src);
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      map: textureLoader.load(hero.src),
      displacementMap: displacementMap,
      displacementScale: 3, // Adjust the displacement scale as desired
    });
    const plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(plane);
    camera.position.z = 3;

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      plane.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();

    return () => {
      renderer.dispose();
      material.dispose();
      displacementMap.dispose();
      material.map.dispose();
      material.displacementMap.dispose();
    };   }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} /> };
```